# Read XML files in R crashes in loops

Tags: r, xml, encoding, xml2

I have a code that loops over a list of xml files and process them. When I execute the code for a single xml, the result is the expected one. But when I start the loop there are unexpected errors in different files. The error's file changes in every iteration so there is no pattern in order to find the error.

Ex. single file:

```
p_xml <- function(file)
{
   tmp<-tryCatch(
  {
    (read_xml(path_XML))
  },error=function(e)
  {
    return(NA)
   })

 if(is.na(tmp))
   {
    file <- read_xml(path_XML, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
  }else{
   file <- tmp
 }
 id <- as.numeric(xml_attr(file, "id"))
 year_id <- as.numeric(xml_attr(file, "machine_year"))

....

return(data)

}
```

This code returns a data.table in the correct way. But if I execute this function inside a loop:

```
global_dt<-data.table()
for(j in 1:length(file_names))
  {
    current_file <- file_names[j]
    f <- p_xml(file.path(current_dir,current_file))
    global_dt<-rbind(global_dt,f)
  }
```

I get an error like this one:

> - Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) :    Failed to parse /path/file.xml
>     *

The fact is that if I then execute the single code with the failed file, it returns what I expected.
I use the xml2 library in order to read the files

Answer (score 0):

try this workflow

```
library(data.table)
#store the result of each run of the function into a list
l <- lapply( list_files, p_xml )
#rowbind the list together into one data.table
global_dt <- data.table::rbindlist( l )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error persists with a different file. The error is the same, but I can update with 3 warnings: In addition: Warning messages:
1: In doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) :
  Too many open file [1518]
2: In doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) :
  Too many open file [1518]
3: In doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) :